# Will I be able to surrender my Indian passport

Tags: indian-citizens, europe, eu, eu-citizens

I'm changing my citizenship to Portuguese but I don't want to surrender my Indian passport in India as I would also have to cancel my voter id and other documents. However if I surrender my passport outside the country I don't have to do that. 
Now I will be traveling outside the country with a visa and on arrival I will show my Portuguese ID. In this case my Indian passport will have an exit stamp but no entry stamp.
In this scenario will the Indian embassy in Portugal give me a surrender certificate?

Comment: You will be committing a crime by not surrendering your Indian passport, after gaining a citizenship of a different country and using it as a travel document. I believe the grace period is 3 months.

Comment: I will be surrendering it withing 1 month of gaining Portuguese citizenship.... and if I use it as a travel document after becoming Portuguese I will have to pay a fine, which I am ready to pay. My concern is, will they accept my application with an exit stamp on the passport but no entry stamp

Answer (score 1):

If a person has ever held an Indian passport and has obtained the passport of another country, they will be required to surrender their Indian passport immediately after gaining another country's nationality.

After Renunciation of Indian Citizenship, it is necessary to apply for Surrender or a Renunciation certificate.

While applying for consular services Visa or OCI, it is mandatory to provide proof of your cancelled Indian passport. If such evidence cannot be provided, applicants will be required to obtain a renunciation certificate.

*It should be noted that it is illegal to continue to use an Indian passport after the renunciation of Indian citizenship and defaulters will be faced with penalties.*

> Now I will be traveling outside the country with a visa and on arrival
>   I will show my Portuguese ID. In this case my Indian passport will
>   have an exit stamp but no entry stamp. In this scenario will the
>   Indian embassy in Portugal give me a surrender certificate?

As it seems you might get fined but at the end of the day you'll manage to get the surrender certificate!

Comment: Do you have a source/reference for this?

Answer (score -1):

Breaking down your question into few parts to understand what exactly you are asking here

`I'm changing my citizenship to Portuguese but I don't want to surrender my Indian passport in India as I would also have to cancel my voter id and other documents. However if I surrender my passport outside the country I don't have to do that.`

OK this makes sense. You can surrender your Indian passport at your local Indian Embassy.

`Now I will be traveling outside the country with a visa and on arrival I will show my Portuguese ID.`

Not clear - where you are travelling to and from where?  And using which passport will you be using?

`In this case my Indian passport will have an exit stamp but no entry stamp. In this scenario will the Indian embassy in Portugal give me a surrender certificate?`

Again - which exit stamp on Indian passport are you talking about?

Comment: Places like Turkey accepts EU ID cards as travel document, which I can get at the Portuguese consulate out here in India without surrendering my Indian passport

Comment: So you are exiting India on Indian passport and using EU-ID card instead of Portugese passport on arrival to Turkey?

Comment: There is a grace period of 3 months to use Indian passport after giving up citizenship. After which for every time you use the passport there will be a fine